# smarty, 1000 to 1K , 1000000 to 1M

Tags: smarty

I'm far from a programmer, just a webmaster and I've been trying to figure out how to get 1K instead of 1000.
After a long time I finally had something working:

```
function insert_viewer_count_format( $options ) {
return ($options['count'] >= 10 ? number_format($options['count'] / 1000, 2) . 'K' : 10);}
```

But.. now it's **only** showing up K, so 10 becomes 0.01K which is kinda silly..

Anybody knows how I can include an if statement in there? I'd also like 1M instead of 1000000.

Thanks a lot in advance, I really appreciate helping me on this!

Comment: First check to make sure that the number is greater than or equal to 1,000 before you convert it to 1K.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$options['count'] = 4000;
if ($options['count'] >= 1000 && $options['count'] % 1000 == 0 ) {
    $result = ($options['count']/1000) . 'K';
} else {
    $result = number_format($options['count'] / 1000, 2);
}
```